# ref cursor integration in spring jpa

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have created a REFCURSOR in postgresql and trying to get the results 
in spring. below is the code I have written:

Entity:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "demoCursor", procedureName = "sf_rc_role", resultClasses = Role.class, parameters = { @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "cashflow_o", mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class) }),
```

Repository :

```
@Procedure
List<Role> demoCursor();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.setHibernateType(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:168)
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:126)
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:63)
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.PositionalParameterRegistration.<init>(PositionalParameterRegistration.java:24)
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.registerParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:260)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.registerStoredProcedureParameter(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.newAdhocStoredProcedureQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:178)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createStoredProcedure(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:130)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:89)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:80)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:299)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy407.demoCursor(Unknown Source)
```

I have Also changed the type to "type = Role.class" in Entity, but didn't get the results. Please help.